# CS50 CAESAR - Different output depending on position of statement, but I don't understand why

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

In the below code, I get different output depending on where I place the 'Printf("Ciphertext: )' statement, and I cannot understand why. Could anyone please point out what I am missing? Below you can find the code, and the output (variable piece in bold).

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[]) 
{
int j = strlen(argv[1]); 
if (argc != 2) 
    {
    printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return (1);
    }  

else 
   { 

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        { 
            if (!isdigit (argv[1][i]))
            {
                printf ("Fail\n");
                return(1);     
            }
        }  

          int convert = atoi (argv[1]) ;


          string Plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");
          int z = strlen(Plaintext);
          **printf("Ciphertext: ");** 

          for (int i = 0; i<z;i++)
          {
             char Ciphertext [z];
             Ciphertext [i] = (Plaintext [i] + 1);
            }


            for (int i = 0; i<z;i++)
          {
              char Ciphertext [z];
              printf("%c", Ciphertext [i]);   
            }
        printf("\n");




    }   



}
```

If I run ./caesar with this code, and enter 'Hey' in the plaintext prompt, the output is Ciphertext: ifz, with which I am happy. However, when I place the printf("Ciphertext: ")Statement to a place that seems more logical to me, I don't get the same output:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[]) 
{
int j = strlen(argv[1]); 
if (argc != 2) 
    {
    printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return (1);
    }  

else 
   { 

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        { 
            if (!isdigit (argv[1][i]))
            {
                printf ("Fail\n");
                return(1);     
            }
        }  

          int convert = atoi (argv[1]) ;


          string Plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");
          int z = strlen(Plaintext);


          for (int i = 0; i<z;i++)
          {
             char Ciphertext [z];
             Ciphertext [i] = (Plaintext [i] + 1);
            }

            **printf("Ciphertext: ");** 


            for (int i = 0; i<z;i++)
          {
              char Ciphertext [z];
              printf("%c", Ciphertext [i]);   
            }
        printf("\n");




    }   



}
```

When I do the exact same here, I print Ciphertext: and an empty row, but it doesn't print out the ciphertext [] as above. Any ideas?

Comment: In your not-working code you create a new variable `Ciphertext`. So what value should it have? You must avoid creating important variables inside blocks; their value will be lost when the block ends.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [usr2564301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2564301/usr2564301) in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111098/cs50-caesar-different-output-depending-on-position-of-statement-but-i-dont-u#comment106314862_60111098), you need to declare `Ciphertext` once so that it doesn't go out of scope.  When it goes out of scope, the old value is formally lost — you may or may not see it again (because it is undefined behaviour to access uninitialized memory, so any result is valid).

Note that although you convert `argv[1]` to an integer, you don't use the result.  The `+ 1` in the encoding means that it appears as if you always supplied `1` as `argv[1]`.  Your code does not do wraparound so that `z` is mapped to `a`.  It doesn't properly handle upper-case and lower-case either.  You probably shouldn't try to encode non-letters, either.  However, this fairly straight-forward adaptation of your code at least produces the semblance of a result:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>    // Needed if atoi() is called
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // This checking is not relevant while the encryption only adds 1
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return(1);
    }
    int j = strlen(argv[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(argv[1][i]))
        {
            printf("Fail\n");
            return(1);
        }
    }
    // int convert = atoi(argv[1]);

    string Plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");
    int z = strlen(Plaintext);
    char Ciphertext[z];

    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        Ciphertext[i] = (Plaintext[i] + 1);    // Should use convert, etc
    }

    printf("Ciphertext: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", Ciphertext[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run (program `cs79` created from source code `cs79.c`):

```
$ cs79 13
Plaintext: Bright vixens jump; dozy fowl quack.
Ciphertext: Csjhiu!wjyfot!kvnq<!ep{z!gpxm!rvbdl/
$
```

Comment: I don't see where the result of the first half of the program is used.

Comment: @S.S.Anne: It isn't used — I commented in the answer that `convert` is not used (and commented it out in the code).  I didn't remove the code that checks that `argv[1]` is all numeric before conversion.  That would be relevant if `convert` were used in place of the `1` in `Plaintext[i] + 1`.  That whole section needs a lot of work (encode letters only; wrap around from `z` to `a`, etc).